# bug with Google oauth when logged in in a different tab on a different service

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

This issue originally popped up when I was writing an application in Meteor.js but I think I have since traced it back to an issue with the google oauth service itself.

The general issue is that if you are already logged in to a single other google account, and then attempt to login to a different service using google oauth in a different tab, then the second one does not give you the option to choose which account, it just assumes you want to login with the account in the other tab and automatically jumps to logged in status:

Steps to reproduce are:

1. open a new incognito window
2. use one tab to login to an existing google service like gmail
3. after doing this use another tab to login to a different service through google oauth (e.g. stackoverflow...this should be done with a stackoverflow account that already exists)

[image]

At the last step the google login service should provide you with an option to select/switch to a different google account, but instead it automatically logs you in with the account that is active in the other tab.

This behavior is fine for google services because they always have the account switcher on the top-right:

[image]

but for stackoverflow and other applications that use google login they do not typically have this same google account switching functionality.

The only way to login with a different google account is to logout of the other google account and then re-try logging in to the secondary app.

I think the correct behavior would be to always show the account selector... or the login option window with the "sign in with different account" option below it
[image]

Comment: A "different tab" on what?

Comment: to be more specific - open a chrome incognito browser window, and the two tabs are tabs in said browser window

Comment: I also having the same issue facing currently. Can anyone helpout on this